# What type of stress does French have

Tags: phonology, phonetics, french, accent, pitch-accent

So I know that there are on the one hand *pitch-accent languages* (like South-Slavic languages, Greek, Norwegian, etc.) where the accentuated syllable is indicated by a particular pitch contour/tone rather than by stress, and on the other hand *languages with dynamic accent* produced by an increased intensity in articulation of the stressed syllable (such as in German or Czech).

Now, am I right in thinking that French has a dynamic accent? I didn't see this stated explicitly anywhere where I looked so I just want to check.
I did however find that French lacks lexical stress entirely which I suppose means that you can't distinguish two identical words just by using a different accent on them?

I'm sorry for my English, I hope everything is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between dynamic stress and pitch accent describes types of word-level "stress" distinctions. So French has neither (and it also is not a tone language). In addition to word stress, tone or simply nothing, a language can (observationally, always does) have a system of intonation superimposed. There is [an article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281318484_Chapter_3_Intonational_Phonology_of_French_Developing_a_ToBI_system_for_French) which proposes a ToBI-paradigmatic account of French intonation.